Repairing/cleaning nozzle assembly for Flashforge/Monoprice Printers
I have a Monoprice MP Voxel, which is a rebranded Flashforge Adventure 3. These printers have an easily removable nozzle assembly, also shared with the Flashforge Adventure 4. The assembly has the nozzle, heater, and temp sensor all built in. I would like to swap out the nozzle, but the assembly is made out of two pieces of injection-molded plastic that are snapped together. I am leery of dropping the entire assembly into a solvent bath. Anyone know how to disassemble this?


